# How to read one dimensional array / vector from csv into R

Tags: r, csv, plot

I have not used R in a while, and I forgot how to do this.  I am outputting about 5000 values separated by commas.  I would like to import them into R and plot them just so I can see the way they are distributed.

File:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,
```

Code:

```
x <- read.csv("output.csv", header=f, sep=",")
plot(x, axes=false, xlab="", ylab="")
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Error in pairs.default(data.matrix(x), ...) : object 'false' not found
```

What is the best way to get this result?

Comment: R is case-sensitive. If you look at `?read.csv` you'll see that by default it uses `header=FALSE`, and `?plot.default` uses `axes=TRUE` by default.  That should be a pretty big clue.

Comment: Hmm, in principle not a bad question that might help several beginners who ran into that same pitfall. Hence I re-worded that question, so someone with the problem has a chance to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy

This is my solution:

Here is the numbers in your file (numbers.csv):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9


x <- read.csv(numbers.csv,header=FALSE,sep=",")

plot(1:length(x),x,axes=F)
```

Answer (score 3):

As was noted in the commemt, R is case sensitive. Therefore, `false` does not equal `FALSE`, the latter being what is correct R syntax. As it does not recognize `false` as a boolean, is searches for an object called `false` which does not exist. As a note, I think it is good practice to use `FALSE` and not `F`. This makes it more explicit what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scan` function:

```
x <- scan("output.csv", sep=",")
plot(x, xlab="", ylab="")
```